# PHPMailer works fine on localhost but not on live server

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have a Contact Form on my website and I need to be able to send the data to my Gmail.

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

  if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $msg = $_POST['message'];

    require_once "PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php";
    require_once "PHPMailer/SMTP.php";
    require_once "PHPMailer/Exception.php";

    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    //smtp settings
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = "@gmail.com";
    $mail->Password = "";
    $mail->Port = 465;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";

    //email settings 
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->setFrom($email, $name);
    $mail->addAddress("@gmail.com");
    $mail->Subject = ("$subject");
    $mail->Body = $msg;

    if($mail->send()) {
        header('location: index.php');
    }
  }

?>
```

This code worked perfectly fine when I used it on my localhost (xampp). But when I tried to use it on my live server it does not work for some reason.

My Gmail has 2-step-verification off and allow less secure access on.

What do I need to change in this code for it to work on live server?

Comment: "does not work" is slightly vague. Is there an error message in any log file maybe? PHPMailer usually throws exceptions, if an error occurs.

Comment: nope the error log does not show any error regarding this

Comment: Ah, I just saw: "$mail->setFrom($email, $name);" Ary you trying to use contact form user's mail address as sender? This will most likely not work. GMail will reject the mail or mark it as spam, because your server is not the "official" mail server for the sender

Comment: Did you enable builtin debug mode of the lib? There's no such in your sample `$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;` also `$mail->addAddress("@gmail.com");` doesn't look good.

Comment: my bad. I forgot to add here. but in the original file, it is there.

Comment: so i should set like  $mail->setFrom("mygmail@gmail.com"); ? Because $mail->setFrom($email, $name); worked on localhost properly.

Comment: @Rohitdesai At least, that's what I would try at first

Comment: no change. no error in error log also.

Comment: You should then evaluate the "else" case of the send() function. PHPMailer provides error information in the "ErrorInfo" field, see here: https://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.PHPMailer.PHPMailer.html#property_ErrorInfo

Comment: and do not forget to check the Spam folder of your account :-)

Comment: Please search for this question - it has been answered hundreds of times before.

Comment: @Roxxorfreak Thank you. I added the else case. I am getting Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. i looked at the GitHub documents and seems like it is a problem with Godaddy.